# Правописание "т. е." — нужен ли пробел?

Tags: орфография, союзы, сокращения, пробелы

Союз **то есть** сокращенно пишется как «т. е.». Насколько мне известно, в подобных сокращениях пробел должен оставаться, поскольку это пробел между двумя сокращенными словами. Однако я часто встречаю написание без пробела, как в интернете, так и, например, в печатных изданиях журналов.
Пишут «т.е.», «т.д.», «т.п.», и т. д. и т. п.

Также недавно встретил рекомендацию такого написания в одном из журналов в их «правилах по оформлению рукописей». Мотивировалось это тем, что при использовании автоматических систем верстки такое написание исключает возможность разнесения двух слов союза на разные строчки и является более удобной альтернативой использованию неразрывного пробела.

Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: с точки зрения русского языка допустимо ли использование слитного написания данного союза и если да, то в каких случаях?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Считается, что да, после любой точки пробел обязателен. Однако в правилах орфографии и пунктуации такого правила нет. Другими словами, это правило верстки, а значит, не столь императивное с точки зрения правописания, подлежащее некоторому переосмыслению.

Я понимаю тех, кто не использует пробел после сокращения в тех случаях, когда сокращение воспринимается как одно слово. Это *"т. е.", "и т. п.", "и т. д."* и инициалы типа *"Иванов И. И."*. Во всех этих случаях пробел между частями, сокращенными до одной буквы, зрительно воспринимается как излишний, но требуется по правилам, диктуемым апологетами орфографического буквоедства. Вынужден подчиняться, хотя и сам постоянно сбиваюсь, и других сторонников слитного написания понимаю. Потому, что "так красивше".

> при использовании автоматических систем верстки такое написание
>   исключает возможность разнесения двух слов союза на разные строчки и
>   является более удобной альтернативой использованию неразрывного
>   пробела.

Это весьма спорный аргумент. Кому-то "более удобная альтернатива" (сам оборот каков!), кому-то - менее. В принципе-то да, неразрывный пробел не всякому автору известен, но кто об их, бедных, удобстве заботится - и давно ли? Нет, думаю, тут вопрос должен решаться только в сфере удобочитаемости, а не *удобописаемости*.

> раздел сокращения:
>   technomag.edu.ru/mdocs/general_paper_specifications.html.

Ага. Вот это особенно позабавило.

> – статья должна быть свободна от орфографических, пунктуационных и
>   стилевых ошибок, большое количество таких ошибок является основанием
>   для отказа в публикации;

Я сходу нашел в самих этих правилах пяток "орфографических, пунктуационных и
стилевых ошибок", включая и само процитированное положение. Ошибки бывают *стилистическими*, *"стилевыми"* - мода, искусство или само стило. Паронимы, конечно, но для редакционных правил как-то очень неаккуратно.

см. здесь.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C
(БТС Кузнецова).

Стилевой - к 1 и 3 значению, у нас здесь значение 4-5.

Answer (score 5):

По поводу автоматических систем вёрстки. Видимо, редакция журнала, предлагающего рекомендацию об исключении пробела, живёт ещё в прошлом веке и даже не подозревает о существовании такого технического средства, как *регулярные выражения*. Так, с помощью простого текстового обработчика `sed` можно провести замену вида

```
sed -r -e "/т[.]\s*([педнкч])[.]/т. \1./g
sed -r -e "/с[.]\s*г[.]/с. г./g
```

Обратите внимание, что в выражениях «на что заменить» употреблён тонкий неразрывный пробел, « » (U+202F в таблице Юникода). (Не знаю, отфильтрует ли StackExchange ввод или нет...)

Чтобы не мучить себя необходимостью прогонять автозамену, можно поставить «Типографскую раскладку Ильи Бирмана» и писать сокращения, подобные «т. е.», с неразрывным пробелом (вводится через Правый Альт + Space). Две кнопки вместо одной. В таблице Юникода имеет код U+00A0.

То же касается сокращённых имён и фамилий. Достаточно написать «Д. И. Менделеев» с неразрывным пробелом, чтобы ни одна система вёрстки (кроме тех, которые по какой-то причине заменяют неразрывные пробелы на обычные) не разнесла инициалы и фамилию по разным строчкам. LibreOffice, например, подсвечивает неразрывные пробелы серым, чтобы было удобно (а в некоторых языках, например во французском, при вводе двухсимвольных знаков препинания автоматически ставит неразрывный пробел). В системе LaTeX при использовании пакета `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` можно писать фамилии через макрос `",` (`Д.",И.",Менделеев`), а неразрывный и тонкий неразрывный пробелы (`~` и `\,`) доступны вообще безо всяких дополнительных пакетов по умолчанию.

**TL;DR:** сочетания вида «и т. п.» принято писать с неразрывным пробелом (U+00A0). После точки можно ставить тонкий неразрывный пробел (U+202F). Однобуквенные предлоги и союзы также принято привязывать неразрывным пробелом. **Слитно писать подобные конструкции не рекомендуется** ввиду наличия упомянутых выше альтернатив.

P. S. Чтобы StackExchange не оставил однобуквенные предлоги на концах строк в настоящем ответе, попробовал привязать их неразрывными пробелами.

Comment: — Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: с точки зрения русского языка допустимо ли использование слитного написания данного союза и если да, то в каких случаях? — спрашивал Glinka 5 мая 2016 г..

Comment: P. S., как и т. е., принято писать через тонкий пробел или через обычный при отсутствии тонкого.

Comment: @shampar Дописал в ответе, что не рекомендуется.

Comment: @Smylic Да, тут Вы меня поймали. Вспоминается случай, как у пожарных сгорела пожарная машина, — здесь то же самое. Исправил.

Answer (score 3):

В русском языке после точки всегда должен быть пробел, как в сокращениях типа *т. е.* или *И. И. Иванов*, так и в конце предложения. То, что вы часто видите в Интернете написание без пробела, это просто признак малограмотности современной публики в Интернете, некоторые даже умудряются не ставить пробелы после запятых или, наоборот, ставить пробелы не после, а перед точками и запятыми.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Про интернет я не сомневался, возможно даже не стоило его упоминать в вопросе. Я имел в виду электронные редакции приличных журналов. Что вы можете сказать по поводу второго абзаца?

Comment: @Glinka нет никаких проблем поставить неразрывный пробел там, где требуется.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я рад что у вас нет никаких проблем. Меня тоже это не затрудняет. Речь идет о том, что слитное написание входит в моду, и это неприятно. Посмотрите, например, здесь, раздел сокращения: http://technomag.edu.ru/mdocs/general_paper_specifications.html. А так, неразрывный пробел ставится во многих случаях: в "т. д.", "т. п.", "т. е.", перед тире, между последним инициалом и фамилией и еще мало ли где.

Comment: @Glinka вы писали про мотивацию не ставить пробел чтобы не пришлось ставить неразрывный пробел. Это - глупая мотивация. Что еще можно сказать цензурного?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо, что выразили вашу точку зрения. Мне она ясна, и я ее разделяю. Хотелось бы ещё увидеть пару слов по этому поводу от автора ответа.

Comment: @Glinka – Думаю, что это они так перестраховываются, не все знают, что такое неразрывный пробел, да и править им без пробела удобнее, в Ворде, конечно, видно тип пробела, но может они в чём-то другом правят, где не видно. Кроме того, по вашей ссылке правила технического вуза, им, видно, особо не до тонких правил русского языка. Что тут ещё добавить?..